# MYSQL: select parent sorted alphabetically grouped with children sorted alphabetically

Tags: php, mysql, database, sorting

I've made a simple table to understand parent-child relationship, but I don't seem to get proper results. I want to sort it

1. first alphabetically by 'name' field, only those who have no parent (parent_id==0)
2. BUT, whenever there are child rows for the parent, they should be printed after the parent, also sorted alphabetically by name.

Example table:

============================================================

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `test`
--

INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `parent_id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 4, 'Zorg'),
(2, 0, 'Woordolack'),
(3, 4, 'Akriller'),
(4, 0, 'Metabrusher'),
(5, 2, 'Intersplitter'),
(6, 0, 'Beaverbrain'),
(7, 4, 'Torgeoruos'),
(8, 2, 'Deptezaurus');
```

============================================================

## Here is what I want to output to a web browser using PHP:

```
 Beaverbrain
 Metabrusher
 -> Akriller
 -> Torgeoruos
 -> Zorg
 Woordolack
 -> Deptezaurus
 -> Intersplitter
```

============================================================

I should say that this is a sample table just to show the idea, so it can be modified in any way to get the proper result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this query

```
SELECT IF(child = '',parent,CONCAT('->',child)) as value 
FROM
    (SELECT parent.name as parent,child.name as child
     FROM test parent 
       INNER JOIN 
       (SELECT id,parent_id,name FROM test 
        UNION 
        SELECT null,id,'' FROM test
        WHERE parent_id = 0)child
     WHERE parent.parent_id = 0
     AND child.parent_id = parent.id
     ORDER BY parent,child
     )parent_child
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed673/7/0)

What the query does is INNER JOIN test with test and find out which are parent and child. The inner UNION `SELECT null,id,'' FROM test WHERE parent_id = 0` creates an empty child(ren) for display purposes. Then the outter SELECT sees if the child is '' it prints out parent, otherwise it concats `->` in front of child. and so you get your result like how you wanted.

The below version might be a little faster. Since we'll just create parents with NULL child instead of using children as part of INNER JOIN (above).

```
SELECT IF(child IS NULL,parent,CONCAT('->',child)) as value 
FROM
 (SELECT parent.name as parent,child.name as child
    FROM test parent 
   INNER JOIN test child ON child.parent_id = parent.id
   WHERE parent.parent_id = 0
  UNION
  SELECT test.name as parent,NULL as child    #This creates a NULL child row
    FROM test WHERE test.parent_id = 0        #for parent display purpose
  ORDER BY parent,child
 )parent_child
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed673/20/0)

I would however use the below query instead and inside PHP, check to see if the `isParent` flag is 1 or 0 and then show the appropriate fields.

```
SELECT 0 as isParent,parent.name as parent,child.name as child,
       parent.id as parentId,child.id as childId
  FROM test parent 
 INNER JOIN test child ON child.parent_id = parent.id
 WHERE parent.parent_id = 0
UNION
SELECT 1 as isParent,test.name as parent,NULL as child,
       test.id as parentId,NULL as childId
  FROM test WHERE test.parent_id = 0       
ORDER BY parent,child
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed673/27/0)

Comment: Wow, it works somehow! This is a pretty much cool example for learning MYSQL (although it's difficult for me to understand). But how will it affect performance if the real table has thousands of records and also left joins other tables to get additional data?

Comment: performance wise I am not sure, depends on indexing but you won't know till you actually run it on actual data. To understand it, you can try selecting(by highlighting) just inner individual selects and run them on the sqlfiddle and you'll see data returning and you'll understand. it's quite simple once you get the hang of it.

Comment: I updated my answer with a different version that might be a little faster and simpler to understand.

Comment: This example is interesting for learning purposes, but in real life, when additional tables are joined and additional values are required, the query becomes really complicated and may require a lot of server resources. For example, if we need additionally grab more values such as id, it should be something like this: SELECT IF(child IS NULL,parent,CONCAT('->',child)) as value, IF(child IS NULL,parent.id,child.id) as value1, etc, which turns it to be even more complicated. I thought maybe it's better to make a kind of simple sorting in MYSQL and stylize the output in PHP?

Comment: update my answer to include a version where inside PHP you can check the `isParent` flag and display the appropriate fields depending on this flag.

Comment: Congratulations! I've checked the last one on a real database and the sorting order looks fine. "3,020 total, Query took 0.0954 sec" and "639 total, Query took 0.0487 sec" with additional where clause. I think it's acceptable time for this kind of sorting. Thanks for your solution!

Comment: if you index parent_id, it should be a little faster.

Comment: It seems to me MySQL has a good caching feature, because when I load the same page several times, it loads in 0.003 seconds.

Comment: @TinTran your answer is really helpful thanks, but the example you gave only display to the second level, how to display up to the third level?

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

```
SELECT
    A.id,
    A.name
FROM 
    `test` AS A LEFT JOIN `test` AS B ON A.`parent_id` = B.`id`
GROUP BY
    A.`id`
ORDER BY
    IFNULL(B.`name`, A.`name`), 
    COALESCE(A.`parent_id`, A.`id`), 
    A.`parent_id` != 0, 
    A.`name`;
```

Answer (score 0):

On managing hierarchical data, You can use a simple PHP recursive function instead,

```
 function DisplayTree( $parent , $depth)     {                                                                                                    
    $sql = $this->db->query("SELECT id,name FROM '$table' WHERE parent_id = '$parent'");

      foreach($sql->result() as $field ) {  
        print "<fieldset style=\"margin-left:$depth%; width:300px\">";  
            print $field->name;
        print "</fieldset>";

        $this->DisplayTree( $field->code , $depth+8 );           
     }  

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a couple of simple queries in PHP,

```
    $r1 = $db->query("select * from test where parent_id = 0 order by name asc") or die('err in q1');
    while($arr1 = $r1->fetch_assoc()){
            $parent = $arr1['name'];
            $parent_id = $arr1['id'];
            echo $parent
            $r2 = $db->query("select * from test where parent_id = $parent order by name asc") or die('err in q2');
            while($arr2 = $r2->fetch_assoc()){
                 $child = $arr2['name'];
                 echo $child."<br />";
            }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, this is the simple and obvious way, but I don't use it because if the table has hundreds of parents, the second query will be executed hundreds of times just to generate one page. And if this page is requested by users several times per second... this will make real performance problems.